# Using Static/Shared C Libraries in Higher Level Languages

Tags: python, c, node.js, shared-libraries, static-libraries

I'm wondering if there is some way to take my custom shared/static libraries, made in C, and use them into another higher language such as python or node.js.

I came with this because I'm writing a few libraries to calculate some math stuff. I heard about node.js not being so good for heavy calculations (but is for networking I/O).

Hence, I'm really thinking on spend some time in find a way to make nodejs to use my C libraries in smart way. I mean, I want to make nodejs delegate the heavy calculations to C, and get the answers back somehow.

But I'm accepting any good advice about using some other higher level languages (or tools) that does the job. Any scenario rather than those I said will be appreciated.

Edit:

I Just Found [this question in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10471459/is-it-possible-to-write-a-node-js-extension-in-c-not-c) that got my attetion. I'll try it for now.

Comment: It is called "native extensions" in node.js, and similar things are possible in most languages. Too big a subject to answer in Stack Overflow with guides and examples. Instead, you could maybe start here: https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html#addons_hello_world

Comment: Matlab has mex functions to interface with C/C++/fortran. C is such a widely used language that usually most higher level language can interface with C, for a lot of them need to use C to implement performance critical functions.

Answer (score 0):

There are not many cases where you would want to do that. I recently tested some heavy math calculations on my pc and on an embedded linux system following Derek Molloy's code from https://github.com/derekmolloy/exploringBB/tree/master/chp05/performance . And I found out node.js does the job in just twice the time C++ (optimized) takes. So this may not be worth your while.